# Symfony Routing Issue After Changing Apache Configuration File

Tags: php, apache, symfony, routes, httpd.conf

I have an issue with my symfony project, Let me explain step by step what changes I made.

1. My old working project:

URL of my old project looks like http://127.0.0.1/my_project/something

***httpd.conf file***

```
Alias /my_project/something/auth /opt/www/my_project/auth
<Directory /opt/www/my_project/auth>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all Granted
</Directory>

Alias /my_project/something /opt/www/my_project/web
<Directory /opt/www/my_project/web>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all Granted

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /my_project/something

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(bmp|css|cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|m?js|png|svgz?|webp|webmanifest|pdf)$ $1.$3 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [PT]
</Directory>
```

And my routes file looks like

***routes.yml file***

```
# routes.yml

get_data:
    path:     /api/select2/get-data
    methods:  [GET]
    defaults:
        _controller: 'my_folder\Controllers\IndexController::apiGetData'
```

The project is working fine with the above configuration.

2. My new project stops working after below my change:

Now I want to change the URL like http://127.0.0.1/my_project/something/MY-SLUG/

For that, I changed my httpd.conf file like

new ***httpd.conf***

```
Alias /my_project/something/auth /opt/www/my_project/auth
<Directory /opt/www/my_project/auth>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /my_project/something /opt/www/my_project/web
<Directory /opt/www/my_project/web>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    DirectorySlash Off

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /my_project/something/
    RewriteOptions AllowNoSlash

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^[^.]+[^\/]$ $0\/ [R]

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !slug=
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/(.*)$ $2?slug=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ ?slug=$1 [L,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(bmp|css|cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|m?js|png|svgz?|webp|webmanifest|pdf)$ $1.$3 [L]
</Directory>
```

I didn't change my ***route.yml*** file,

I want to set MY-SLUG in session and then use it everywhere in my project, But after changing this I can't able to access any route of my Symfony project. I don't want that change in my httpd.conf file to affect my project, I just want MY-SLUG from URL.

Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [PT]

The reason for the route not to work is that your second config is not pointing to Symfony’s entry file app.php

Comment: I am using index.php instead and I also tried with app.php it is not working